# How to invoke ical sync service?

Tags: cocoa, icalendar, syncservices, calendar-store

I have an application that syncs with iCal through the Calendar Store framework. I've noticed that I need to open iCal for the sync service to start and transfer events and tasks added with my application to my ipad and iphone. So.. my question, is there a way to start ical sync service without opening ical?

Thank you,
Jose.

Comment: Probably not the most helpful suggestion, but have you considered using `CalendarStore` instead?

Comment: Thats what I'm using, but accessing the Calendar Store Framework does not automatically sync with iphone or other computers. When I open iCal, iCal updates the CalendarStore database with the truth (Sync services)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive that it will pick up the latest changes made to CalendarStore, but you should be able to trigger iCal's sync client by launching (NSWorkspace would do):

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CalendarStore.framework/Resources/iCalExternalSync`

This is the sync tool iCal uses to interact with Sync Services.

Comment: Good suggestion, though I'm not able to initialize the sync function. The program does start and ends with exit code 0. I also tried giving it single number parameters but It didn't work.